# Will this particular breaker box allow ground wire to connect at neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, neutral

[image: OP's image]

House is ran with EMT.. I have two dedicated circuits coming in from outside the house for a swimming pool, with a dedicated ground to the main breaker box.

I want to connect to far right bottom neutral bar, to stay as far away from lugs from main feed as I can. I just want to make sure this specific box allows that.

Comment: https://imageshack.us/i/pmcK5q9hj

Comment: Does the heavy green wire top, center go to a grounding rod? I see a green screw top, right. I understand that this screw bonds the neutral bus to the ground bus. Is that right? If so, how does it do that?

Comment: @JimStewart ill have to double check. I know there is a grounding rod right outside. The green wire, I believe goes to the main copper water pipe as the pipe comes into the house.

Comment: It should go to both. The incoming cold water line is required to be grounded and the panel has to be connected to the ground rod.

Answer (score 2):

I see what appear to be 4 wires coming in to the top lugs. So I think this is a sub-panel, not your main panel. If that is true, ground and neutral are separate, and must be carried separately back to the main panel.

Comment: This is my main panel.

Comment: Then you can mix grounds and neutrals.

Answer (score 1):

It's alright for you to connect neutrals and grounds to the bus. If you will notice there are green wires (grounds) at the left hand side connected to the bus already. There is a bond screw at the top right and it is the first means of disconnect. In short it meets all of the requirements.

Comment: As long as this is your main panel they can be connected if it is a sub from your main the neutral should be isolated from ground.

Comment: This panel would be very wrong for a sub, given how they have commingled neutral and ground.

Comment: Yes your main service panel allows mixing neutrals and grounds. The neutral and ground wires are attached to the same lug at the top of the panel and as RTM noted the green bonding wire is installed.